# How to Connect Python, Oracle 11g with cx_Oracle in linux server?

Tags: python, linux, oracle11g, server, cx-oracle

My oracle install folder in linux server is "/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib"

setting variables in ~/.bash_profile are

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib

export ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Also, link in folder "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib"

```
ls -al|grep libclntsh.so

## Results are:
libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1
libclntsh.so.10.1 -> /oracle/app/pracle/product/11.2.0/lib/libclntsh.so
libclntsh.so.11.1
```

And in python

```
os.environ['ORACLE_HOME']
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']

## Results are:
'/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64'
'/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib'

import cx_Oracle ## This Part is ok
```

But, This code are Error

```
cx_Oracle.clientversion()
## or 
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('ip',port,'SID')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='uid',password='pwd',dsn=dsn)

## Above Code Results:
DatabaseError:Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
```

I doubt that my folder "/etc/ld.conf.d" has not "oracle-instantclient.conf" file.
 This folder only has "mariadb-x86x64.conf"
ip, port, SID and userid, password all correct!

What's wrong my oracle connect setting in linux server?

Comment: Did you look up for ORA-01804, which tells "initialization failure for timezone information".

Comment: If you are using an instant client, do **not** set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. It's my fault.
I just change the ORACLE_HOME & LD_LIBRARY_PATH and It's running.

```
os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = 'oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0'
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = 'oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/lib'
conn = oci.connect('ID/pw@localhost:port/SID')
```

Solved it.